# Creating tables with something similar to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_DEFINITION in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, create-table

Is there a standard method to retrieve the 'CREATE TABLE..' definition of a table in SQL Server?

I can ask INFORMATION_SCHEMA for definitions of views and functions/procedures, so I thought it would be natural to get the same for tables, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`** should be what you're looking for.

It will give you something like:

```
aspnetdb    dbo    aspnet_Paths                      BASE TABLE
aspnetdb    dbo    aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers    BASE TABLE
aspnetdb    dbo    aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser     BASE TABLE
aspnetdb    dbo    vw_aspnet_WebPartState_Paths      VIEW
aspnetdb    dbo    vw_aspnet_WebPartState_Shared     VIEW
aspnetdb    dbo    vw_aspnet_WebPartState_User       VIEW
aspnetdb    dbo    aspnet_Applications               BASE TABLE
```

If you want to know about the columns of a table, look at **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`**.

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'aspnet_Users'
```

will give you all the details for the columns for the table specified.

Comment: I know that I can find alle the information in those tables, but I was looking for an automatic way to retrieve the complete create-script including all constraints for a table, just as I can get it when working in MSSQL Management Studio.

Comment: I don't think you can just "find" the complete create script anywhere in any of the system catalog views. If you want a complete script, you need to use SMO, as Nestor suggested - it has a function to script out any kind of database object - which probably just inspects those system catalog views and concatenates together the info into a full create script.

Answer (score 1):

Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA for views and code will *fail*. The data is limited to nvarchar(4000), so longer stuff will not be read. Use [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) or [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx).

For tables, it's more difficult. A "table" consists of columns, constraints, indexes, possibly rules, UDTs (did I forget anything?). This is why SSMS has so many table scripting options compared to a view or stored proc.

I'd suggest profiling SSMS and hope it doesn't use SMO... or use SMO via CLR code or even xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMO (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) from .NET to script the table.

Comment: oh I see.. sorry, i didnt understand your question.